# mysqldump several tables with parameters

Tags: mysql

I need to backup the entire database, but I need it to have date parameters, so I must include that's why I'm including each table separately, but when I execute the command it sends me the following error

```
mysqldump -u root -p --insert-ignore --no-create-info --lock-tables=false prueba --tables fechas fechas1 alumno --where="fecha > curdate() - INTERVAL 2 DAY">dbdatos2.sql

mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ `idalumno`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `materia`, `calificacion`, `estatus` FROM `alumno` WHERE fecha > curdate() - INTERVAL 2 DAY': Unknown column 'fecha' in 'where clause' (1054)
```

The name of the DB is "prueba".

Thanks for your time.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems pretty clear:

> Unknown column 'fecha' in 'where clause'

This error is reported for a specific table `alumno`.

Does that table have a column named `fecha`? I am confident that it does not.

When you use the `--where` option, the expression must be valid for *all* tables you are dumping. That means if you reference a column name, the column must exist in all the tables you name.

Comment: the column "fecha" only exists in the table "fechas", the other tables do not contain that field, in such a case as I can proceed I cannot increase that field to all the tables, can i make that condition only for the "fechas" table?

Comment: No, the condition is applied the same to all tables you are dumping. There is no way to make a different condition for specific tables. The only alternative is therefore to run mysqldump more than once.